# Hyperledger Composer v0.16.0 network start error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying Hyperledger Composer v0.16.0. According to this [procedure](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-single-org.html), I want to Deploy BNA to Fabric network on cloud. but following error occurs.
Kindly let me know how I can solve it.

command:

```
composer network start --card PeerAdmin@myfabric --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --archiveFile trade-network.bna --file networkadmin.card
```

result:

```
tarting business network from archive: trade-network.bna
Business network definition:
    Identifier: trade-network@0.1.13
    Description: Commodities Trading Business Network

Processing these Network Admins: 
    userName: admin

✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to instantiate composer runtime. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: chaincode instantiation policy violated(Failed to authenticate policy))
```

Comment: The first you need start fabric. Run ./startFabric.sh in fabric-dev-servers.

Answer (score 4):

`Error: No valid responses from any peers` may be b/c you don't `./startFabric` (in `fabric-tools` folder) or may be the `.acl` file (permissions.acl) have error (try change it to the beginning version).

Answer (score 3):

The error 'Error: Error trying to instantiate composer runtime.' Suggests you have not run the composer runtime install command e.g.
`composer runtime install -c PeerAdmin@fabric-network -n tutorial-network`
Or that the command did not complete successfully.

The other possibility is that your fabric has stopped or is not contactable.

Comment: Installed the card again but still facing the same issue

Answer (score 2):

The runtime must be installed on fabric for the network to start.

"composer runtime install -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -n "

The Steps:

**1)** ./startFabric.sh,

**2)** ./createPeerAdminCard.sh,

**3)** composer runtime install -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -n ,

**4)** composer network start -a ./@0.0.1.bna  -A admin  -S adminpw  -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1

Answer (score 2):

```
there seems to be some challenges / bug with the use of composer
```

Composer Updates : 0.19.0 Changes:

End of March developers of Composer framework released version 0.19.0. Although there are multiple new features (mostly under the covers) in this release, it also introduced some BREAKING changes :( So what does that mean? It means that:

Some of the composer CLI commands have become obsolete *or have* changed

BNA Installation commands have changed ( install + start )

Following Composer CLI commands have been removed

runtime install, network deploy, network update, network undeploy

BNA upgrade requires an install of new version followed by

Composer card commands standardised to use -c or --card. Earlier some commands used -n and some used -c

Some of the Composer API have changed

Answer (score 1):

That error can mean that the identity you are using to perform a network start doesn't have channel admin authority and thus is not authorised to perform a network start. I would suggest you check with whoever created your Hyperledger Fabric environment and channel to find out who the right identities are for administrative authority on the channel and build a card with the appropriate crypto material representing that identity in order to perform a network start.

Answer (score 1):

```
 1. ./stopFabric.sh
 2. export FABRIC_VERSION=hlfv11
 3. ./startFabric.sh
 4. ./createPeerAdminCard.sh
 5. install network
 6. start network
```

Answer (score 0):

Please create a new card with your business network name. Hopefully it will work:

**composer network start --card PeerAdmin@myfabric --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --archiveFile trade-network.bna --file *trade-network*.card**

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution to my problem, which is similar to yours, it might be useful to you too:

I noticed that with other networks it works properly so, there is a problem with the DNS:

1. Edit or create */etc/docker/daemon.json* in your machine and add:
   `{ "dns": ["your dns", "8.8.8.8"] }`
2. Stop Fabric, restart Docker, Start Fabric
3. Repeat composer install and composer start

Answer (score 0):

Well i was getting the similar error :-

```
Upgrading business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to upgrade business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message: could not find chaincode with name 'airlinev9')
Command failed
```

My composer version: v0.19.4

What I was trying to do:-

I was trying the update my BNA to a newer version. But got the error which i shown you above.

What I did to solve the issue :-

1. I first deleted the previous card using the command :-

> composer card delete -c admin@airlinev9

2. And then start the BNA with (already created, installed):-

> composer network start -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -n airlinev9 -V 0.0.3 -A
>   admin -S adminpw

And it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am SUPER new to HyperLedger hence I am not sure on how it worked out me but just in case might work for you too so try it out. I did only 2 things((on fabric-tool directory) :

```
1) ./startFabric.sh

2) ./createPeerAdminCard.sh
```

Ok I agree I lied. Not 2 things but 3.

3) Retry .bna association as expected normally.

I hope it works for you too :)