# unable to establish a network in Hyper-fabric composer from OS X

Tags: docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

In Hyperledger composer, **composer network start** always fails with the following error.

```
*"Error trying to instantiate composer runtime. Error: Error: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE"*.
```

But I installed the runtime environment for the same card using **composer runtime install**. My machine is under proxy, but in ignore list, I added the peer domain name too.

I installed the docker too.

[I referred the previous posts but that solution also I tried but it didn't help me. Please guide me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625538/hyperledger-composer-v0-16-0-network-start-error)
[Attached the screenshot of terminal with the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3EXt.png)

Comment: What version of Mac OSX  ? -> Have you checked the pre-requisites here (including the supported OS' ?) - also you will need to ensure you meet the https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html - Did you pull down the Fabric as documented? What steps were you executing, as which user etc.

Comment: 10.12.5 Sierra OS Version I'm Using and I am having admin privileges too. I followed the same tutorial for installing and I successfully installed all the requirement. I checked my docker and it shows the peer0 which I have started was running on it. Now, When I planned to deploy the business network, Please refer the below mentioned tutorial step 5 section. While creating network card I am facing the above mentioned issue. https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-single-org.html

Comment: hi there, thanks. I would definitely not install with admin privileges - it causes problems for the npm package installer. This could be part of what you're seeing (difficult to tell with so little info). I suggest to uninstall and clean up your install, then follow this https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions to resolve npm so that you can install as a non-privileged user (which is what Composer requires).  Also ...(cont'd) ...

Comment: ....as shown [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html) - see 'Step 2', bullet 2. - do a `teardownFabric.sh` of your Fabric (and pull a new set of Fabric images as per the sequence shown there). FYI I just looked at your previous link  - seems to me you didn't *import* the 'admin' business network card created following the `composer network start` ...ie using `composer card import` command - see Step 9 of that tutorial

Comment: Hi I got installed and established a network and the issue is I ran these commands behind proxy hence somewhere firewall didn't allow me to create network.