# Hyperledger composer v0.16.2 Rest server error

Tags: rest, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am working composer v0.16.2. I am having an error while I try to reconnect to composer-rest-server.

I am using this command:

`composer-rest-server -c admin@mynetwork -n always -a true -m true -w true -t true -e /home /.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/cert.pem -k /home /.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/key.pem`

Whatever the option I set it works fine first time but when I need to reconnect with the same command, I need to restart fabric and deploy the business network again otherwise it will show this error:

```
Discovering types from business network definition ...
Connection fails:
Error: Error trying to ping.
Error: Error trying to query business network.
Error: Connect Failed It will be retried for the next request.
Exception: Error: Error trying to ping.
Error: Error trying to query business network.
Error: Connect Failed Error: Error trying to ping.
Error: Error trying to query business network.
Error: Connect Failed at _checkRuntimeVersions.then.catch (/home/.../.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:713:34)
                      at <anonymous>
```

[Hyperledger Composer v0.16.0 network start error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625538/hyperledger-composer-v0-16-0-network-start-error)

I found a similar question on this link but I need to start fabric again when this error comes and again deploying network archive help to start the rest server.

My question is how can I remove this error without starting fabric again when I need to start rest server?

Comment: There is not really enough information here - what command did you use? What are your steps leading up to the error?   Are you using samples/tutorials or your own Business Network?  Has your Business Network been deployed?

Is your Fabric started?  Have you seen the answer to this post which describes checking and starting a Development Fabric? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47767190/hyperledger-composer-error-identity-has-not-been-registered-once-issued-after-re

Comment: I am using composer-rest-server to create a rest server on my own business network. @RThatcher

Comment: what output do you get if you do composer-rest-server -v ? what output do you get when you do composer -v ?

Comment: @david_k v0.16.2 for both composer -v as well as composer-rest-server -v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first action of the REST server is to 'Discover' the Business Network using the admin@mynetwork Card.  So you can simplify testing here by not using the REST server, but by issuing a simpler command `composer network ping -c admin@mynetwork`  or  `composer network list -c admin@mynetwork`.

When your admin@mynetwork card is created (when you deploy the business network), then imported **BEFORE** you use it try the command `composer card list --name admin@mynetwork`  - at the bottom of the output you should see:

`secretSet:           Secret set
credentialsSet:      Credentials not set`

After you use the card for the first time with a composer network ping or list, redo the `composer card list --name admin@mynetwork` and you should see a change in the output with **Credentials set**.

This is important because when the Card is created, it is created with a One Time secret, and when it is first used the Certificates are downloaded - Credentials Set.  The problem you are seeing with a failure of the REST server the second time you use it suggests that the certificates needed for the second use are not present.