# getting Error in starting hyperledger business network

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I had followed all the steps of configuring the hyperledger business network using this [link](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/business-network/bnd-create).

I had configured all the steps but i am stuck at the very last step of starting my business network.I am getting this error

```
 Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid 
 responses from any peers.
 Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: failed to 
 execute transaction 
 6581ef4cc7b6fec6c0b69af693acb62d2690588288e5174d38fa86fcf90fef94: 
 error starting container: error starting container: Failed to 
 generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 
 1 "npm WARN notice [SECURITY] js-yaml has the following 
 vulnerabilities: 1 high, 1 moderate. Go here for more details: 
 https://www.npmjs.com/advisories?search=js-yaml&version=3.10.0-Run 
`npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm 
audit` to get more info.
```

Please help me to solve this out.

My Enviorment:-

```
docker:- 18.09.7
docker-compose:-1.21.2
Node:-8.10.0
Npm:-6.9.2
Hyperdledger Fabric:-1.2
Composer:-0.20
```

Please help me to figure out this issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625538/hyperledger-composer-v0-16-0-network-start-error

Comment: tried this link but not getting useful information and have same error @LinSel

Comment: Can you please let me know in which OS are you working on?

Answer (score 0):

The following are prerequisites for installing the required development tools:

```
Operating Systems: Ubuntu Linux 14.04 / 16.04 LTS (both 64-bit), or Mac OS 10.12
Docker Engine: Version 17.03 or higher
Docker-Compose: Version 1.8 or higher
Node: 8.9 or higher (note version 9 and higher is not supported)
npm: v5.x
git: 2.9.x or higher
Python: 2.7.x
```

If you're running on Ubuntu, you can download the prerequisites using the following commands:

```
curl -O https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/prereqs-ubuntu.sh

chmod u+x prereqs-ubuntu.sh
```